# The Http of FSharp.Data and proxy server

Tags: f#, f#-3.0, f#-data

I'm creating a program to download web pages using the Http module of FSharp.Data. However, the module doesn't support setting http proxy server. In C# there is

```
_httpWebRequest.Proxy = 
    new System.Net.WebProxy("http://proxy.myCompany.com:80", true);
```

I tried to download the file from https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/master/src/Library/Http.fs and use it directly in my F# project. However, the type of `response` changed from `string` to `HttpResponse` after I call the `Http.Request` from the downloaded file.

```
let response = 
    Http.Request (
        url, 
        query=["userid", user; "password", password; "login", "Sign+On"], 
        meth="POST", 
        cookieContainer = cc)
```

What's the best way to extend the Http module with proxy support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FSharp.Data 2.0, you can pass the parameter `customizeHttpRequest` of type `HttpWebRequest->HttpWebRequest` to set the proxy like this:

```
Http.Request (
    url, 
    query=["userid", user; "password", password; "login", "Sign+On"], 
    meth="POST", 
    cookieContainer = cc,
    customizeHttpRequest = (fun req -> req.Proxy <- WebProxy("http://proxy.myCompany.com:80", true); req))
```

Answer (score 2):

In the new version (upcoming release), we are renaming the current `Http.Request` to `Http.RequestString` and the current `Http.RequestDetailed` to `Http.Request`. This is a breaking change, but we thing it makes much more sense (and fits better with standard .NET naming). If you just want to copy the old file, you can always get the older version of the code from the appropriate branch on GitHub (e.g. [Http.fs @ tag v1.1.10](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/blob/v1.1.10/src/Library/Http.fs)).

However, I think that supporting HTTP proxies would be a great addition to the library. So the best thing to do would be to fork the project to your GitHub, add the feature and submit a pull request! I think that just adding an optional `?proxy` parameter to the two methods and propagating the information to the underlying `HttpWebRequest`would be the best way to do this.

The only tricky thing is that `Http.Request` should work on multiple versions of .NET (including Windows Phone, Silverlight, etc.) so you may need to check which of them actually support specifying the proxy.

If you do not have the time for helping out, then please submit [a GitHub issue](https://github.com/fsharp/FSharp.Data/issues?labels=status-consider&state=open).

Comment: Thanks. Another missing feature may be functions for downloading huge files. Right now it uses all `ReadToEnd` for downloading? I've very new to F#. I will fork the project when I get more familiar with F#.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding the proxy globally with `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy("http://proxy.myCompany.com:80", true)`?